# How to retrieve VS syntax colours

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am building a more advanced editor for VS 2017 / 2019.  However, one of the things which is important is to maintain the same colours as defined by the user / theme the user has chosen.

Now, for all the environment colours (that is, all aspects of VS which are not the contents of the editor window), these are easily obtained via the method

```
VSColorTheme.GetThemedColor(themeResourceKey);
```

Using the predefined themeResourceKeys as defined in

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.EnvironmentColors
```

So, for example, to retrieve the background color key for the tool window background, you call the following

```
VSColorTheme.GetThemedColor(EnvironmentColors.ToolWindowBackgroundColorKey);
```

What I am after is the keys of the colors being used by VS to color class names, comments, line number, privates, publics, statics, etc, all colors used in the editor.  With these color keys, I'd like to then use these code keys to call a VS extensibility class or method to retrieve the actual colours being used.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how the editor is retrieving these actual color keys, and how I can use these to retrieve the currently set color?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this blog](https://keyoti.com/blog/visual-of-the-actual-colours-in-visual-studios-environmentcolors/) makes some help when you choose suitable code keys.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that post.  Thanks for that.  Unfortunately, the way colours are actually rendered in the editor is, at best, odd.   At present, Microsoft doesn't expose those colours as easily-accessed parameters.